# Redirect the output of gstreamer to OpenCV

Tags: linux, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, gstreamer

How can I redirect the output of gstreamer to OpenCV (on linux using python), so I can preform image processing?

**EDIT**:
this is my current code:

```
./receive_video.py | gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

and I wish to redirect the produced video to openCV.

**EDIT 2**:
my code for `receive_video.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import sys
import time

def convert_2_bytes_array(x):
    data=x.split(':')
    my_bytes = bytearray()
    for elem in data:
        my_bytes.append(int(elem,16))
    return my_bytes

TCP_IP="172.16.10.1"
TCP_PORT=8888
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

try:
    TCP_sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    TCP_sock.settimeout(5.0)
    TCP_sock.connect((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
    magic_word=convert_2_bytes_array("00:01:02:03:04:05:06:07:08:09:28:28")
    TCP_sock.send(magic_word)
except:
    exit(-1)
t0=time.time()

while(1):
    try:
        data = TCP_sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        # sys.stdout.write(data) # python 2.7
        sys.stdout.buffer.write(data) # python 3
    except ValueError:
        print(ValueError)
        break
    if time.time()-t0>1:
        t0=time.time()
        try:
            TCP_sock.send(magic_word)
        except:
            exit(-1)

TCP_sock.close()
```

Comment: added. note that receive_video.py recives data from camera and output it to sys.stdout.

Comment: do you know how can it be done using python and working on linux?

Comment: done! it must send the magic word every second in order to get the tcp stream from the camera

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174554/discussion-between-zindarod-and-tome8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally got it, this is the solution I came up with:

```
pipe = sp.Popen(["receive_video.py"], shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10 ** 8)
pipe2 = sp.Popen(["gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! filesink location=/dev/stdout"], shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stdin=pipe.stdout, bufsize=10 ** 8)
```

and then:

```
while True:
    raw_image = pipe2.stdout.read(720 * 1280 * 3)
    image = numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
    image = image.reshape(720, 1280,3)
    cv2.imshow('Video', image)
```

Explanation:
The stdout from `receive_video.py` is sent to pipe2 as stdin. By applying the command `filesink location=/dev/stdout`, gstreamer sents it's output to dev/stdout. This output is later caught by the command `pipe2.stdout.read`, which goes to opencv `imshow`

There is a problem with the image, as you can see here: 
[odd image using cv2 and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454239/odd-image-using-cv2-and-numpy), however it works and video can be recived in opencv.