# odd image using cv2 and numpy

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am running the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy
f = open("raw_image",'rb')
raw_image = f.read(720 * 1280 * 3)
image = numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
image = image.reshape((720, 1280, 3))
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

and I get this result:
[image]
the image is RGB image with height of 720p and width of 1280.
Any Ideas how to solve it?

**EDIT**: I receive images from a camera with resolution of 720x1280. The image is a colored image. The file `raw_image`, which I read the bytes from, contains the output from the command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! filesink location=/dev/stdout
```

As you can see, the received image is malformed, and I dont know how to fix it.

**EDIT2:** this is the raw image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hPRUEVNFiKmiUFbzksUlzzC04teml4hw/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT3:** after running the code (NOTE: I am displaying only the first 720*1280 bytes):

```
raw_image = f.read(720 * 1280 * 3)
raw_image=raw_image[:720 * 1280]
image=numpy.frombuffer(raw_image,dtype='uint8')
image = image.reshape((720,1280))
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I got this result:
[image]
When I move some of the left part to the right, by adding the line:

```
image=numpy.concatenate((image[:,141:],image[:,:141]),axis=1)
```

I got a fine image:
[image]

can it help solving the mystery?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not quite clear on your question, what you want to achieve? why did you want to reshape your image to the same dimension? CV2 displaying this distorted image is your problem?

Comment: I have add some more information :)

Comment: What does this command `gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! filesink location=/dev/stdout` does? is it responsible for disorting the image? have you varified that first?

Comment: Can you share the image please? Then folks can work on it without guessing. Thank you.

Comment: done! good idea!

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a Red-Blue gradient like this with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal, you will see that your code works fine:

```
convert -size 1280x720 gradient:red-blue -depth 8 rgb:raw_image
```

[image]

---

I deduce your `gst` stuff is *"unhappy"*.

---

The image you have shared contains this:

[image]

I converted it to a JPEG using **ImageMagick** like the in the Terminal:

```
convert -size 1280x720 -depth 8 rgb:raw_image.dms result.jpg
```

I deduce again that your `gst` stuff is *"unhappy"*.

Comment: I am not sure that the gst staff is unhappy, since I can get a nice image from it's output (see EDIT3), do you have an idea why is it happening?

Comment: Your code works fine on correct data that I generated. The `gst` data you provided to me and the data you used yourself both generate incorrect images. The conclusion, and my answer, is that your Python is correct and your `gst`-streamed data has errors in it.

Comment: when I use the code: `gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! filesink location=/dev/stdout` I get the displayed result. However when I use the code: `gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! xvimagesink sync=false` it works jest fine, but the image is displayed on separate widow (and not using opncv). That is the reason I think the output of `gst` is fine

Comment: Go to the other end of your processing chain where you produce images. Generate an image of random data and send the same one 1,000 times. At the receiving end, pick up each frame and save as raw data without any processing. Generate md5 checksums for all files and see if they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if you still need help here, but for those who have the shift in the image, it is due to extra "progress" data gstreamer spit out into the stdout. you need to add the quiet option.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -q ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the same odd image: the image was splitted in perfect 3x2 which is can of odd. The program worked perfectly well and then the entire video was layed like that. This is kind of bugs are pure nightmares as they are not blattant code errors. They involve some magic to find the culprit.

Story short: the issue come from the encoder gstreamer or ffmpeg that expects 3 channeled rgb colors instead of pure grayscale. To solve the issue either reconstruct a three channeled rgb from grayscale or pass the pixel format gray to encoders. Refer to respective documentation for exact syntax.

Story long: encoders are gas engine with unexpected behavior. They are gray zones must scrutinized...